# Number of $n$-letter words with some restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $n, n_1, \ldots, n_k, m, m_1, \ldots, m_k$ be positive integers such that $n = n_1 + \cdots + n_k$, $m = m_1 + \cdots + m_k$, and $m_i \geq n_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,k$). I have an alphabet $A$ of $m$ distinct letters, and $A$ is divided into $k$ pairwise disjoint sets $A_1, \ldots, A_k$, with $A_i$ containing $m_i$ letters ($i=1,\ldots,k$).

How many $n$-letter words with exactly $n_i$ letters from $A_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,k$) are there?

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{n}{n_1}$ ways to choose places for letters from $A_1$. Then there are $\binom{n - n_1}{n_2}$ ways to choose places for letters from $A_2$ etc. Multiplying these numbers we get $\binom{n}{n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k} = \frac{n!}{n_1!\cdot n_2! \cdots n_k!}$ ways to choose places for sets of letters.

If places for letters from $A_i$ are chosen there are $m_i^{n_i}$ ways to place certain letters to these places. So the answer is
$$\frac{n!}{n_1!\cdot n_2! \cdots n_k!} \cdot m_1^{n_1} \cdot m_2^{n_2} \cdots m_k^{n_k}.$$